# What is effect of marking contact as deceased?

Tags: contacts

What is the effect of marking a contact as deceased?  Does this automatically stop email traffic to the contact's email address

Answer (score 6):

Deceased should have the following outcomes (iirc):

- Contact Record shows (deceased) in red after their name
- CONTACT IS DECEASED shows in demographic fields
- contact is excluded from mailings and PDF prints
- contact is excluded from emails
- contact is excluded from exports unless overwritten
- the status of memberships will be changed to "deceased"

Comment: Also the status of memberships will be changed to "deceased"

Comment: Excellent. added to above.

Comment: I really think this information should be included in the CiviCRM documentation somewhere as I found this information really hard to find.

Comment: maybe time to cut your teeth on helping with the documentation via https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide

Comment: (saying this to my co-worker so it isn't quite as blunt as it may read to others ;-) )